# I want to make my linear layout center of Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` , in that I have a `LinearLayout` , I placed 2 `ImageButton` in `LinearLayout` , what I actually want is , my `LinearLayout` should be in the center (horizontal) of `RelativeLayout` , how can I do that ?

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@color/test"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add centerinparent=true in linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in LinearLayout as follows :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />    

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

it might help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes it is .Perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@color/test"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this code will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for linearlayout. Weight won't work in RelativeLayout, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

in you LinearLayout and also you may want to change the width of LinearLayout

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

so the image buttons are centered horizontally

Answer (score 1):

insert `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for linearlayout. Weight won't work in RelativeLayout, so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to LinearLayout.